# Radio селектор и XHTML

Tags: xhtml

Будет-ли такой код правильным в XHTML?

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options в помощь.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

> "VI delimiter" is a technical term for the equal sign. This error message means that the name of an attribute and the equal sign cannot be omitted when specifying an attribute. A common cause for this error message is the use of "Attribute Minimization" in document types where it is not allowed, in XHTML for instance.

> How to fix: For attributes such as compact, checked or selected, do not write e.g <option selected ... but rather <option selected="selected" ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не будет. будет правильным вот такой

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" />
```